# C# - Peek Queue over time Without timer. Is it possible?

Tags: c#

My current code is inside a timer to keep comparing `if all drones actual position is near desired position` but I dont think this is the best approach because I think this leads to slow processing.

**Is there a way to check if the actual position is near desired position without using peek inside a timer?**

```
 private void timer_missao_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] pontos_separados = null;

        for (int k = 0; k < drone.Length; k++)
        {
            if (queue[k].Count > 0)
            {

                if (queue[k].Peek() == "levantar")
                {
                    drone[k]._droneClient.FlatTrim();
                    drone[k]._droneClient.Takeoff();
                    drone[k].subir_ate_altura = true;
                    queue[k].Dequeue();


                }


                else if (queue[k].Peek().Split(null)[0] == "goto")
                {
                    pontos_separados = queue[k].Peek().Split(null)[1].Split(',');
                     drone[k].posicao_desejada = new PointF(Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[0]), Convert.ToSingle(pontos_separados[1]));

                    int precisao = 5;

                    if (drone.All(d=> d.pos_atual().X > d.pos_desej().X - precisao && d.pos_atual().X <d.pos_desej().X + precisao &&
                        d.pos_atual().Y > d.pos_desej().Y - precisao && d.pos_atual().Y < d.pos_desej().Y + precisao))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < drone.Length; i++)
                        {
                            queue[i].Dequeue();
                        }

                    }
                }
                else if (queue[k].Peek() == "aterrar")
                {

                    drone[k]._droneClient.Land();

                    if (drone[k]._droneClient.NavigationData.State == NavigationState.Landed)
                    {
                        queue[k].Dequeue();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the check only when the drone positions are updated, and not on every tick. That way you can also skip the `Peek`, by having the code that updates the drone position pass the updated Drone object to your check function.

Comment: drone_actual position is being updated 30 times per second.

Comment: @user7569125: Well, you do have some code that reads the drone position, right? E.g. from the network or similar. This code is something like this pseudocode `var message = ReadNextMessage(); if(message.Type == "Movement") { drones[message.DroneID].Position = message.NewPosition; }` and since here you have a reference to the drone that has moved, you can also do something like `CheckIfNear(drone);` after the `Position` assignment.